# Where can i find AWS EC2 X.509 Certificate private key

Tags: amazon-ec2

Only the cert-xxxxx.pem can be download.

Can not find the create new key pair link in my account, but found it in source code, and created the new key pair.

Comment: Really? This question doesn't belong here!

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, AWS does not retain a copy of your private key.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#X509Credentials

> If you have us generate your X.509
>   certificates, we give you a
>   PEM-encoded certificate file, and a
>   PEM-encoded private key (unencrypted,
>   which means you don't get a password
>   for it). You'll need to convert the
>   files to whatever format your toolkit
>   uses (see the toolkit's documentation
>   for help). Even though we provide you
>   the private key, we don't store it
>   anywhere. If you lose it, you must
>   switch to using a different X.509
>   certificate.
>
> If you provide your own keys, you must
>   upload only your certificate to AWS
>   (you keep the private key). The
>   certificate must be in PEM format. AWS
>   accepts any syntactically and
>   cryptographically valid, unexpired
>   X.509 certificates. They don't need to
>   be from a formal Certificate Authority
>   (CA).